# How to encode url in order to get request in $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my function inside the controller:

```
      event.preventDefault();
      url=event.target.href;                        
      var data=productionService.getUrl().get({
        urlvalue:encodeURIComponent(url)
      }, function(success){
        window.open(success,'_blank');
      }, function(error){
        alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(error))
      });
    } else {
      window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
  }
}
```

and inside the factory:

```
getUrl:function(){
  return $resource("requesturl?id=:urlvalue");
}
```

The 404 error occurs when clicking the url and the url has `http%25...` instead of `http://`
what can i do to fix this error.

Comment: Why do you have http%25?

Comment: that is shown in the alert error it has to be http:// and this is what i am unable to do

Comment: GET http://someurl?somevalue=http%253…%252F03..%252 404 (Not Found) is shown in browser console . i have removed some values inside it with .... for confidentiality

Comment: http%3A%2F%2F  try this

Comment: i am sending url as a parameter .the url contains http://xy/xz/.. and when the request is made ,error occurs and at browser console i see that the url is converted to http%25... i used encodeurlcomponent but this didn't help

Comment: have you tried to replace `encodeURIComponent(url)` with `url`?

Comment: @Aprillion yes i did try that way also

Comment: with the same error? what about `decodeURIComponent(url)`?

Comment: @Aprillion when not used decodeuricomponent 404 error .http:// converts to http%2f%2f and while using decodeuricomponent 404 error with http:// converted to http%253a%252f%...

Comment: @RameshKhadka have you replaced the built-in `decodeURIComponent` function by a custom function? there is no way the built-in version would convert `http://` to `http%253a%252f%` which is a double-*encoded* uri string - http://jsfiddle.net/Aprillion/3onu3hmn/ (well, it could be decoded from `decodeURIComponent("http%25253a%25252f%25252f")`)

Comment: i had to decode the url in backend so the problem is solved .thank you guys for your valuable suggestions.. i appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

That because of you using encodeURIComponent as per example in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

The result of res will be:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

what you want is

```
getUrl:function(){
 return $resource(encodeURIComponent("requesturl?id=:urlvalue"));
}
```